# How to get Latest N Records of selected Group

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, sql-order-by

I want to run a query on `MySql version 5.1.9` that returns me only top two (order by JoiningDate) of selected Dept.

For example, my data is like:

```
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+------------+
| empid | title                                    | Dept     | JoiningDate|
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+------------+
|   1   | Research and Development                 | 1        | 2015-08-06 |
|   2   | Consultant                               | 2        | 2015-08-06 |
|   3   | Medical Consultant                       | 3        | 2015-08-06 |
|   4   | Officer                                  | 4        | 2015-08-06 |
|   5   | English Translator                       | 5        | 2015-08-06 |
|   6   | Teacher                                  | 1        | 2015-08-01 |
|   7   | Physical Education                       | 2        | 2015-08-01 |
|   8   | Accountant                               | 3        | 2015-08-01 |
|   9   | Science Teacher                          | 4        | 2015-08-01 |
|  10   | Home Science                             | 5        | 2015-08-01 |
|  11   | Research Assistant                       | 1        | 2015-08-05 |
|  12   | Consultant                               | 2        | 2015-08-05 |
|  13   | Consultant HR                            | 3        | 2015-08-05 |
|  14   | Technical Lead                           | 4        | 2015-08-05 |
|  15   | Hindi Translator                         | 5        | 2015-08-05 |
|  16   | Urdu Teacher                             | 1        | 2015-08-02 |
|  17   | Physical Education                       | 2        | 2015-08-02 |
|  18   | Accountant                               | 3        | 2015-08-02 |
|  19   | Science                                  | 4        | 2015-08-02 |
|  20   | Home Science                             | 5        | 2015-08-02 |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+------------+
```

I want the query to output the latest joined two empid's of Dept (1,2,3) i.e:

```
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+------------+
| empid | title                                    | Dept     | JoiningDate|
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+------------+
|   1   | Research and Development                 | 1        | 2015-08-06 |
|  11   | Research Assistant                       | 1        | 2015-08-05 |
|   2   | Consultant                               | 2        | 2015-08-06 |
|  12   | Consultant                               | 2        | 2015-08-05 |
|   3   | Medical Consultant                       | 3        | 2015-08-06 |
|  13   | Consultant HR                            | 3        | 2015-08-05 |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: order by `JoiningDate` right?

Comment: Create a sql-fiddle for sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql you can use user defined variables to achieve you desired results

```
SELECT 
t.empid,
t.title,
t.Dept,
t.JoiningDate
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    @r:= CASE WHEN @g = b.Dept THEN @r + 1 ELSE 1 END rounum,
    @g:= b.Dept
    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM table1 
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r:= NULL,@g:=NULL) a
        WHERE Dept IN(1,2,3)
        ORDER BY Dept,JoiningDate DESC
    ) b
) t
WHERE t.rounum <=2
```

[**`DEMO`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/888f7/3)

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated sub-select to count number of rows with same date but a later JoiningDate. If less than 2, return the row.

```
select empid, title, Dept, JoiningDate
from tablename t1
where (select count(*) from tablename t2
       where t2.Dept = t1.Dept
         and t2.JoiningDate > t1.JoiningDate) < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
select *
from emp_ t1
where 
(
    select count(*) from emp_ t2
    where t2.Dept = t1.Dept
    and t2.JoiningDate > t1.JoiningDate
) <= 1
and t1.Dept in (1,2,3)
order by t1.Dept;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/038cd7/1)

---

Can also achieve it by giving a rownumber.

**Query**

```
select t2.empid,
t2.title,
t2.Dept,
t2.JoiningDate
from
(
   select empid,
   title,
   Dept,
   JoiningDate,
   ( 
       case Dept 
       when @curA
       then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
       else @curRow := 1 and @curA := Dept end
    )  as rn
    from employee t,
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r
    where Dept in (1,2,3)
    order by Dept,JoiningDate desc
)t2
where rn < 3;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b7e5/1)